# Conditional Column Formatting

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
  cat df1 df2 df3
1   1  NA   1  NA
2   1  NA   2  NA
3   1  NA   3  NA
4   2   1  NA  NA
5   2   2  NA  NA
6   2   3  NA  NA
```

I want to populate df3 so that when cat = 1, df3 = df2 and when cat = 2, df3 = df1. However I am getting a few different error messages.

My current code looks like this:

```
df$df3[df$cat == 1] <- df$df2
df$df3[df$cat == 2] <- df$df1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code. What have you tried? What are the errors you are getting? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: `ifelse(data$cat==1, data$df2, data$df1)`

Comment: @Jimbou in your example also when cat is not 2 (E.g 3, 4, ...) you will have df3=df1...

Comment: @Terru_theTerror you are right but I followed the example data. And there are only `1:2`'s. So my code is giving the correct output.

Comment: Yes, it's true, but I think is better to provide a generic and robust solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
ifelse(df$cat == 1, df$df2, df$df1)
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3

# saving 
df$df3 <- ifelse(df$cat == 1, df$df2, df$df1)

# if there are other values than 1 and 2 you can try a nested ifelse 
# that is setting other values to NA
ifelse(df$cat == 1, df$df2, ifelse(df$cat == 2, df$df1, NA))

# or you can try a tidyverse solution. 
library(tidyverse) 
df %>% 
  mutate(df3=case_when(cat == 1 ~ df2, 
                       cat == 2 ~ df1))
cat df1 df2 df3
1   1  NA   1   1
2   1  NA   2   2
3   1  NA   3   3
4   2   1  NA   1
5   2   2  NA   2
6   2   3  NA   3

# data
df <- structure(list(cat = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), df1 = c(NA, NA, 
                           NA, 1L, 2L, 3L), df2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, NA, NA, NA), df3 = c(NA, 
                           NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("cat", "df1", "df2", "df3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
                           "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
df[df$cat==1,"df3"]<-df[df$cat==1,"df2"]
df[df$cat==2,"df3"]<-df[df$cat==1,"df1"]
```

The output:

```
df
      cat df1 df2 df3
    1   1   1   1   1
    2   2   1   2   1
    3   3   1   3  NA
    4   4   2  NA  NA
    5   5   2  NA  NA
    6   5   2  NA  NA
```